# Xcode cloud - Grant access to Your Source Code, Unknown error

Tags: xcode, git, source-control-explorer

On Xcode cloud after reviewing workflow, I receive an unknown error on granting access to the source code.

Screenshot:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQfJa.png)

I am trying to connect to Xcode cloud but received this unknown error and cannot continue.

Comment: Seems like your repository has been wrongly set up. Try to re-setup your repository. Maybe you don't have added your SCM provider account to Xcode, if this is needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure GitHub is setup to work with Xcode. https://medium.com/@adrian.creteanu/link-your-xcode-project-with-github-5d1aeb582b08
2. Add remote branch.
3. When going through Xcode cloud steps make sure to click on `edit workflows` (right before the `Grant access to your source code` screen and pick the Github repo as your primary repo.

[Xcode source control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXx33.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I fixed it.

1. Verify that your SCM provider account (like GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, etc.) is properly connected to Xcode.
2. Make sure that your code repository is correctly pushed to your SCM provider. If it’s not available on the provider, Xcode Cloud cannot access it.